# ASP.NET Wizard's sidebar shrink when step panel too wide

Tags: asp.net, wizard, sidebar

I'm using ASP.NET Wizard control to display a wizard with a Gridview displaying the contents of each step.

In the Gridview, there are several columns using Textboxes to display the content. When the content in the Textbox get longer, the step panel gets wider and makes the Sidebar shrink.

I've set the Sidebar (`SideBarStyle-Width`) and the step panel (`StepStyle-Width`) to use fixed width (in percentage) but the Sidebar keeps being shrunk.

I also got the width of columns (`ControlStyle-Width`, `ItemStyle-Width`) in the Gridview fixed in percentage, but that doesn't work either.

The only thing that works is to fix width of columns in the Gridview with a specific value in `px`, but I must keep these columns to dynamically resize for different resolutions.

Is there any way to keep the Sidebar untouched when the conten size changes?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but with the following properties now it's working fine. Be sure to set `AutoPostBackOnSelect="true"`.

Here's a sample of my grid header:

```
<ComponentArt:Grid ID="grdProducts" runat="server" AllowMultipleSelect="false" AllowColumnResizing="false" RunningMode="Client" AutoPostBackOnSelect="True" PageSize="10" PagerStyle="Slider">
```